# How to list HDFS directory contents using webhdfs?

Tags: python, json, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Is it possible to check to contents of a directory in HDFS using `webhdfs`?

This would work as `hdfs dfs -ls` normally would, but instead using `webhdfs`.

How do I list a `webhdfs` directory using Python 2.6 to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `LISTSTATUS` verb.  The docs are at [List a Directory](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#LISTSTATUS), and the following code can be found on the [WebHDFS REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) docs:

With `curl`, this is what it looks like:

```
curl -i  "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"
```

The response is a [FileStatuses JSON](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#FileStatuses) object:

```
{
  "name"      : "FileStatuses",
  "properties":
  {
    "FileStatuses":
    {
      "type"      : "object",
      "properties":
      {
        "FileStatus":
        {
          "description": "An array of FileStatus",
          "type"       : "array",
          "items"      : fileStatusProperties
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[fileStatusProperties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#fileStatusProperties) (for the `items` field) has this JSON schema:

```
var fileStatusProperties =
{
  "type"      : "object",
  "properties":
  {
    "accessTime":
    {
      "description": "The access time.",
      "type"       : "integer",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "blockSize":
    {
      "description": "The block size of a file.",
      "type"       : "integer",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "group":
    {
      "description": "The group owner.",
      "type"       : "string",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "length":
    {
      "description": "The number of bytes in a file.",
      "type"       : "integer",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "modificationTime":
    {
      "description": "The modification time.",
      "type"       : "integer",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "owner":
    {
      "description": "The user who is the owner.",
      "type"       : "string",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "pathSuffix":
    {
      "description": "The path suffix.",
      "type"       : "string",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "permission":
    {
      "description": "The permission represented as a octal string.",
      "type"       : "string",
      "required"   : true
    },
    "replication":
    {
      "description": "The number of replication of a file.",
      "type"       : "integer",
      "required"   : true
    },
   "type":
    {
      "description": "The type of the path object.",
      "enum"       : ["FILE", "DIRECTORY"],
      "required"   : true
    }
  }
};
```

You can process the filenames in Python using [pywebhdfs](http://pythonhosted.org/pywebhdfs/), like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient

hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='host',port='50070', user_name='hdfs')  # Use your own host/port/user_name config

data = hdfs.list_dir("dir/dir")  # Use your preferred directory, without the leading "/"

file_statuses = data["FileStatuses"]
pprint file_statuses   # Display the dict

for item in file_statuses["FileStatus"]:
    print item["pathSuffix"]   # Display the item filename
```

Instead of `print`ing each object, you can actually work with the items as you need.  The result from `file_statuses` is simply a Python `dict`, so it can be used like any other `dict`, provided that you use the right keys.

Comment: Can this be used to retrieve the filenames inside a directory?

Comment: It *completely and totally* depends on what language you're trying to use to do this.  Since you hadn't included that in the original question, I assumed that it was immaterial to you, and that you'd work it out once you knew the verb to use.  If you update the question with details on which language (C++, Python, Ruby, PHP, Fortran, etc) you're using, that would make it possible to answer that question.  Please be as detailed as possible (e.g. Python 2.7 is different than Python 3.0, Ruby 1.8.7 is different than Ruby 2.3.1, C is different than C++, etc).

Comment: Sure the language we're using at the moment is python

Comment: I have updated the question for you.  (note that I had asked you to *update the question* already.)  Please confirm that's what you're actually asking.